How to shorten logger name while using log4net with log4net.Ext.Json
When not using json one can use %logger{1} syntax
<layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern
                value="%date{yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fff} [%logger{1}] - %message />
</layout>

What is the way to achieve the same while using
    <!-- A1 uses PatternLayout -->
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.SerializedLayout, log4net.Ext.Json">
        <decorator type="log4net.Layout.Decorators.StandardTypesDecorator, log4net.Ext.Json" />
        <member value="className:logger" />

